# Error base de datos con XAMPP: "mysqli::query(): (HY000/1034): Clave de archivo erronea para la tabla"

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo una pagina en PHP y van varias veces que mi xampp o phpadmin me pone este error:

```
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php#209
 mysqli::query(): (HY000/1034): Clave de archivo erronea para la tabla: 'global_priv'; intente repararlo

Backtrace

DbiMysqli.php#209: mysqli->query(
string 'SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user LIMIT 1',
integer 0,)
DatabaseInterface.php#219: PhpMyAdmin\Dbal\DbiMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user LIMIT 1',,integer 0,)
DatabaseInterface.php#1713: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(string 'SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user LIMIT 1')
SqlController.php#158: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->isSuperUser()
Routing.php#192: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Sql\SqlController->__invoke(
,array,)
index.php#43: PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute(,string '/sql',,,)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que estas usando?

Comment: Perdon son muchos archivos, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tn0VHN1irqE&list=PLH_tVOsiVGzmn89QxjFTCE19rLSDqG03U&index=119 de aqui lo estoy haciendo y van varias veces que me hace ese error que comente

Comment: Te dejo los archivos bueno la liga de github     https://github.com/Carlos007007/PRESTAMOS/tree/master/vistas/contenidos

Comment: siempre acabo reinstalando el xampp y funciona un rato bien y despues vuelve al mismo error, incluso no se si sera por lo que hago o si sea otra razon

Comment: Aunque ya haya pasado cierto tiempo: el [repro] debe ir _en la pregunta_, no a través de enlaces externos. Lee [ask].

Comment: En esta página dan una solución que a mi me funcionó espero que a tí también https://unasolucion.com.mx/blog/2022/09/28/warning-in-librariesclassesdbaldbimysqli-php/

Answer (score 1):

El día de hoy en mi servidor local me empezó a salir un mensaje en PhpMyAdmin con la siguiente leyenda:

Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php#209

Por más que daba en ignorar cada que refrescas la página vuelve a salir, afortunadamente es muy sencillo solucionarlo.

Tendremos que ir a nuestra carpeta donde está instalado mysql (en mi caso uso XAMPP) C:\xampp\mysql\bin y vamos a buscar y ejecutar el archivo mysql_upgrade.exe.

Después de hacerlo actualizamos PhpMyAdmin y listo, problema resuelto, ojalá te sea de utilidad.